# Practical considerations for EM clustering

Tags: clustering, likelihood-ratio, expectation-maximization, fuzzy

EM algorithm guarantees finding a local rather then global minimum of the likelihood. As a consequence, the results are dependent on the initial conditions (e.g., if randomly choosing the initial cluster centers.) Some tutorials that I have seen mention running the EM algorithms several times in such cases. This however entails several practical considerations:

- How many times to run the algorithm?
- How to choose more fiable solutions?
- How to represent the results, if multiple solutions could be reasonable?
- How to estimate the optimal number of clusters, privided multiple solutions?
- When to give up altogether on clustering / mixture-modeling for the given dataset?

**Background:** I am clustering data in the context of [enterotyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterotype), i.e., assigning microbial compositions to several typical compositional types.

**Update: Gelman-Rubin criterion**
I wonder whether there exist anything in the spirit of [Gelman-Rubin criterion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/262037/110833) used in a similar setting: when a mixture model is analyzed with Markov chain Monte Carlo technique. The criterion compares the variance among the MC threads launched with different initial conditions, and the variance within thread - the ratio that should converge to 1, if the number of the MC steps is sufficient.

**Update 2: MC-EM and SAEM**
Another approach, that partially an alternative to multiple re-runs of the EM, is Monte Carlo Expectation Maximization. See [Rationale for MCEM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161888/rationale-for-mcem) and [Avoiding burn-ins in MC-EM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/322575/110833) for more discussion, as well as [A New Class of Stochastic EM Algorithms. Escaping Local Maxima and Handling Intractable Sampling](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02044722v4/file/2020_AllassonniereChevallier.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

```
How many times to run the algorithm?
```

There is no hard rule for the number of repetitions. The number should increase with the dimension of the parameter but the spread of the starting values matters as well.

```
How to choose more fiable solutions?
```

The absolute rule is to take the solution with the highest observed likelihood. If the likelihood cannot be computed, a Monte Carlo approximation
could be used.

```
How to represent the results, if multiple solutions could be reasonable?
```

If the likelihood values cannot be computed, there is no way to pick one.

```
How to estimate the optimal number of clusters, provided multiple solutions?
```

Express the number of clusters in terms of the latent variables and compute its expectation given the EM estimate of the parameters.

```
When to give up altogether on clustering / mixture-modeling for the given dataset
```

There is no answer without further details.

Comment: Thanks, what you say makes a lot of sense, and some of these judgements are certainly subjective. I however hoped for an estimate for a number of reruns, to be statistically reliable. Also, increasing the number of clusters increases the number of parameters - is it appropriate to use AIC or BIC here?

Comment: It is correct that you cannot estimate the number $k$ of components by sheer MLE. AIC, BIC, or WAIC are penalisations that can be used for this purpose. Here is a [reference that tries to address this problem](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229009009_Detecting_the_Number_of_Clusters_during_Expectation-Maximization_Clustering_Using_Information_Criterion).

Answer (score 0):

This does not fully answers the question as posed, but came up as a practical approach to K-means clustering:
`one runs the algorithm multiple times, choosing the realisation that minimizes the desired loss function, as the one representing global minimum.`

This is, e.g., the approach adopted by the [scikit-learn realization of K-means](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html):

> `n_init int, default=10`
> Number of time the k-means algorithm will be run with different centroid seeds. The final results will be the best output of n_init consecutive runs in terms of inertia.

> `inertia_ float` Sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center, weighted by the sample weights if provided.

This strategy is also discussed in thread [Avoiding local minima when using Kmeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43789602/6151828)